# remove all web parts/web zones/widgets

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I am creating web part. I created a page with page template "Unique Page". I attempted to reduce the number of 'areas' on the page.

I clicked on one of the web parts and clicked on "remove all web parts". Now that I am browsing the site to see that all the pages are now blank. There is only the header and footer visible on every page.

Every page, in Page tab and Design tab don't provide options on the page. There are no web zones, no web parts, no widgets.

Any clue as to what the issue is?

Comment: As posted, you really haven't given anything to work with. Please edit your question to show your page template, code, screenshots, or whatever else you can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds as if you removed the page placeholder webpart.  Go back to the master page template and in the content zone add in a Page Placeholder webpart with the default settings.  This should fix the issue.

Comment: All the pages are displaying content again. Thank you!